# Detect Liveness of the user by using visual speech recognition ( LipRead)

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow, android-jetpack-compose

How can I implement liveness detection in my Android application using visual speech recognition without audio? I want to turn on the camera, display a random 4-digit number, and verify if the user has read it to detect if the user is fake or not. I've looked for solutions but couldn't find anything suitable. Any suggestions, especially if they involve TensorFlow files, would be appreciated.

I've been exploring options to implement liveness detection in my Android application. Initially, I attempted to integrate existing Python libraries for visual speech recognition into my Android project but encountered compatibility issues. I've also researched TensorFlow models for liveness detection but haven't found a suitable solution tailored for Android. Ideally, I was expecting to find a TensorFlow model or a similar resource that I could easily integrate into my Android app to achieve the desired liveness detection functionality.